2021: a year in moderation

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year.
As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

That doesn't eliminate the need for having moderators altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.
So as we say goodbye to 2021, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some exciting stats. Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Cryptography over the past 12 months:




Action
Moderators
Community¹




Users suspended²
1
15


Users destroyed³
12
0


Users deleted
4
0


Users contacted
4
0


Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue
78
958


Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue
5
86


Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue
1
155


Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue
0
164


Tasks reviewed⁴: First questions queue
6
519


Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue
2
1,227


Tasks reviewed⁴: First answers queue
0
123


Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue
84
1,000


Tags merged
2
0


Tag synonyms proposed
5
1


Tag synonyms created
4
0


Questions reopened
36
0


Questions protected
1
5


Questions migrated
85
1


Questions merged
12
0


Questions flagged⁵
3
311


Questions closed
605
112


Question flags handled⁵
172
136


Posts unlocked
1
20


Posts undeleted
20
57


Posts locked
10
105


Posts deleted⁶
209
1,250


Posts bumped
0
746


Comments undeleted
38
0


Comments flagged
0
106


Comments deleted⁷
1,200
1,385


Comment flags handled
97
9


Answers flagged
0
269


Answer flags handled
236
33


All comments on a post moved to chat
11
0



Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Cryptography without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁵ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: 2020: a year in moderation

You can also check out this report on other sites

Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites


Wishing everyone a happy 2022! ^_^

Our first post queue is halved in 2021. One possible reason is we have lots of basic questions that cover them, though it is amazing that new contributors ask some basic questions that never approached or SO is not gaining new users as in previous years. What about other SO sites? Same result?

If anybody has any questions about the stats to the moderators, then feel free to ask. Of course, users destroyed are mainly due to spam(-egg-bacon-and-spam). At least from my side: I try and leave closing questions to the community, although I do try and give them a push if they are at 2/3 close votes already. Thanks JNat, I hope that the generation of the stats has become a bit more transparent :)

FYI, I've made a comparison table
